# Parallax background-position

Tags: java, jquery, css, html

I am trying to achieve a scrolling effect using jQuery.
i have background-position change depend on window.scroll top value, the problem that background-position It is moving in the wrong direction so i need any solution make background-position moving in the It is moving in the right direction.

### HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var imgThumb = $(".blur .img-thumb"),
            backPosition = $(".blur .img-thumb div"),
            windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop()
        imgThumb.css('right', windowScroll * 3);
        backPosition.css('background-position', windowScroll * -.66 + "px" + " 50%");
        console.log(windowScroll * -.66)
        if (windowScroll == 0) {
            backPosition.css('background-position', "-245px" + " 50%");
        }
});
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height:6000px;
}
.blur{
    width:100%;
    height:620px;
    position:fixed;
    background:url("http://store1.up-00.com/2016-09/1472892032111.jpg") no-repeat center center;
}
.blur .img-thumb{
    position:absolute;
    width:420px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
.blur .img-thumb img{
    width:100%;
}
.blur .img-thumb div{
 width: 129px;
 height: 189px;
 position: absolute;
 background: url("http://store1.up-00.com/2016-09/1472892032252.jpg") no-repeat -245px center;
 top: 85px;
 left: 184px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="blur">
        <div class="img-thumb">
            <img src="http://store1.up-00.com/2016-09/1472892032323.png" alt="Alternate Text" />
            <div style="background-attachment:scroll;"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```